# Does Azure Postgresql support table view replication?

Tags: azure, azure-postgresql

I want to use  replication only for **table view** which I have defined.
However, looking at online [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/concepts-read-replicas#connect-to-a-replica) , this seems to be not possible since *server name* and *location* is available for parameters.

[image]

Is it possible to only replicate **table view** using replication for *Azure DB for PostgresQL*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it doesn't.

Azure PostgreSQL as a solution provides a managed database-as-a-service. Consequently, the solution addresses concerns with enablement at the infrastructure level. Therefore, a replication is only applicable to the server.